# Can you optimise the choice of array for the Oracle IN clause

Tags: oracle

I have a table which holds timestamped streaming data for events, it can be created like:

```
create table event_data
(
    event_id integer,
    date timestamp,
    ... -- other data corresponding to the stream
);
create index ed_event_id on event_data(event_id);
create index ed_date on event_data(date);
```

Now this table has a lot of information and I would like to retrieve data in batches of events. To this end, I have constructed a `where` clause like:

```
select * from event_data
where event_id in (event_id1, event_id2, ...);
```

For the purposes of retrieving data in batches like this, does it matter whether the event_ids supplied in the array have any particular order or are part of any particular subset?

E.g. should I supply the first N events, then the next N events, and so on and so forth, according to the event_date column?

Would a random subset in the `IN` clause perform just as well? Why, and why not?